# pdf.js gem producing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am a rails novice and trying to create my web portfolio in Cloud9. I wanted to display my resume.pdf in the user browser so I installed this gem `gem 'pdfjs_rails'` now my app doesn't even start in cloud 9. It show the following error messages in the terminal:
[image]

Please help me. How can i revert it back? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like anything related to pdfjs (no point in that direction). Are you sure you've selected the right runner in Cloud9? See:
https://community.c9.io/t/error-when-running-ruby-project/11799/4

More in general: if you think an issue would be related to a gem, you can simply remove it from the Gemfile and run `gem bundle` to 'revert' to a previous state.